# como fazer um evento usando a tecla enter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de saber como que eu faço para fazer um sistema tipo o `onclick` ou o `click` se for jQuery.

Quando o usuário apertar a tecla `enter` em um formulário ele automaticamente clique no botão e envie o formulário com o `click`.

Eu sei fazer mas gostaria de aprender esse método também.

codigo:

```
 <script>
        $("#envia").click(function(){
            var campo = {
                nome: $("#nome").val(),
                email: $("#email").val(),
                assunto: $("#assunto").val(),
                message: $("#message").val()
            };

            if(!campo.nome || !campo.assunto || !campo.email || !campo.message){
                $.alert({
                title: 'Atenção',
                content: 'Todos os campos sao obrigatorios!',
                });
                return;
            }

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Esse é o comportamento padrão de um formulário, sem usar javascript.

Comment: Se o último campo for um `textarea` você precisará usar JavaScript.

Comment: meu ultimo campo e textarea mas como eu poderia usar para fazer isso quero que ele faca as mesmas coisas que eu programei no evento click do jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar este código

```
$(function(){
    $('input, textarea').on('keypress', function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#BotaoId").click();
        }
    });
});
```

Caso você entenda de inglês tem uma resposta que também te ajudaria com `javascript` puro [SO Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905222/enter-key-press-event-in-javascript)

---

Seu código deve ficar parecido com esse

```
$(function(){
    $('input, textarea').on('keypress', function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#envia').click();
        }
    });

    $("#envia").click(function(){
        var campo = {
            nome: $("#nome").val(),
            email: $("#email").val(),
            assunto: $("#assunto").val(),
            message: $("#message").val()
        };

        if(!campo.nome || !campo.assunto || !campo.email || !campo.message){
            $.alert({
            title: 'Atenção',
            content: 'Todos os campos sao obrigatorios!',
            });
            return;
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: poderia me explicar onde eu coloco essa função pois estou vendo que ela e uma função anonima e funções anonimas são atribuídas geralmente em alguma coisa eu devo atribuir isto ao botão? no caso eu tentei implementar seu codigo dentro da funcao do botao e ele nao vai ele nao vai no textarea nos outros ele envia chega no textarea ele nao manda nada

Comment: No jQuery, quando você declara o nome da tag, classe ou id `$('input, textarea')`, você já esta atribuindo para esses elementos o comportamento da função, você pode passar diversos elementos utilizando a mesma função, para saber detalhes da função [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: tipo cara ele nao ta dando enter quando eu estou no textarea nos outros inputs ele vai mais no textarea nao

Comment: Ve se no console apresenta algum erro, segue o exemplo funcionando [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qrcc7n0v/)

Comment: não apresenta erros no console se eu postar meu trecho de código você me mostra onde devo implementar? deve ser onde estou implementando

Comment: Pode sim, edita sua pergunta e adiciona o seu código

Comment: pronto ja editei

Comment: Adicionei na resposta como deve ficar, caso você tenha mais `input` ou `textarea` na sua página altere essa parte `$('input, textarea')` colocando os `id's` dos campos que você quer que a função funcione

Comment: pode cre vlw man obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Não precisa de tudo isso. Basta o `form` ter um `input` do tipo `submit` que o enter em qualquer `input` dispara o `submit`.

Answer (score 3):

Podes usar um evento delegado. Delegado na form mas que verificas para ter certeza que estás certo do que vai acontecer e qual o elemento em que estás. Por exemplo:

```
$('#idDaMinhaForm').on('keyup', function(e){
    if(e.which != 13) return; // não é o "enter"
    if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'input') this.submit();
});
```

#### Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/x36bzdn9/